# jquery mobile 1.4 form input makes the CPU 100% on iOS app on focus for at least 30 seconds

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, input, cpu

This might be a wierd behavior, haven't found any topic about. But maybe one of the gurus out there can help.

Using cordova 3.x

I have a form with input fields. Multipage jquerymobile 1.4. iPhone and iPad iOS 7. Both has the same issue. Android no issue.

When I load the very first time the App and I try to type in any of the input fields, the CPU goes 100% and after a while (30 sec) the field goes focus and the cursor blinking like normal. Then after this (apparently freezing eternal lasting) time, everything works.

If I close the app and open it again, no problems at all.

What could be the reason and where can I start looking for this weird odd and nasty bug?